# GO, GAE, remote api and local datastore

Tags: google-app-engine, go

I am completely new to GAE using Go (actually using anything. new to GAE). and I am completely lost. I have a small application, whose yaml file looks like this

```
application: my-niceapp-636
version: beta
runtime: go
api_version: go1

handlers:

- url: /_ah/remote_api
  script: _go_app
  login: admin

- url: /static
  static_dir: static
  application_readable: true

- url: /.*
  script: _go_app
  login: admin
```

I am writing it in GO. and followed this guide here

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/go/tools/remoteapi#enabling_remote_api

in my main file I added this import -- _ "appengine/remote_api" and when I hit the URL

```
http://localhost:8080/_ah/remote_api
```

i see this ->

```
This request did not contain a necessary header.
```

However when I hit the same URL in remote (in the appspot domain) the default index page is served. I do not understand why is that. is it normal? Maybe yes, but for noob like me not at all.

I have copied the entire code of the go_appengine/demos/remote_api/datastore_info.go to my own gae application dir and renamed it as import_data.go and changed the part that reads from a file the password instead hard coded the password in the file. that is the only difference. I give you that part of code bellow

```
var (
    host         = flag.String("host", "", "hostname of application")
    email        = flag.String("email", "", "email of an admin user for the application")
    //passwordFile = flag.String("password_file", "", "file which contains the user's password")
)
.
.
.
.
/*if *passwordFile == "" {
        log.Fatalf("Required flag: -password_file")
    }*/

    //p, err := ioutil.ReadFile(*passwordFile)
    /*if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Unable to read password from %q: %v", *passwordFile, err)
    }*/
    password := "xxxyyyzzz112233"//strings.TrimSpace(string(p))
```

Everything else remains the same. After all these when I am trying to run it via

```
goapp run import_data.go -email myemail@gmail.com -host my-niceapp-636.appspot.com
```

I get this error ---

Failed to create context: unable to contact server: token not found: want "7790585182047258325";

after which it spits out the whole index file that we will usually see when we visit the app.

I am completely lost and to be truthful I have had much better experience with Go involving linode or Amazon. Shame on google that they made things so complicated.

How, if needed, am I suppose to access the remote data store from my localhost application?

Can any body please help me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `login: admin` means you have t be logged in as administrator to access the resource.

Comment: so does that mean that I remove that from my yaml file and try to run the demo program?

Comment: well, tried after removing that. The same effect. GAE is making my life super complicated!

Comment: Turned out to be the problem that I have actually never deployed the code in remote using goapp deploy. That takes me to another q though. is there a way of push deployment for go app in GAE? the control panel for that mentiones Python and PHP.

Comment: I'm not sure, you should post another question

Comment: I should but what shall I do with it? delete you think? I guess that is better.